# How to delogo center in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

How to delogo on center image in ffmpeg? To delogo top left, I use something like this.

`ffmpeg -i tes.png -vf "delogo=x=10:y=10:w=40:h=40" a.png`

But for delogo on center image, I experiment like this but show error.
`ffmpeg -i tes.png -vf "delogo=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2:w=40:h=40" a.png`

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for all replies that tell me that delogo only accept absolute integer. Maybe my next strategy is measure width & height of image via ffmpeg, calculate, then set as value of delogo. I'll accept an answer who able to make that script work automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delogo only accepts absolute integer values.

You need to do a circuit that ends in an overlay.

```
ffmpeg -i tes.png -filter_complex "crop=60:60:(iw-ow)/2:(ih-oh)/2,delogo=x=10:y=10:w=40:h=40[dl];[0][dl]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto" a.png
```

Comment: I got an error when try that command. Please see my updated question

Comment: [overlay @ 0x5574e72c46c0] [Eval @ 0x7ffdfefcbc90] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'auto'
[overlay @ 0x5574e72c46c0] Unable to parse option value "auto"
[overlay @ 0x5574e72c46c0] [Eval @ 0x7ffdfefcbce0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'auto'
[overlay @ 0x5574e72c46c0] Unable to parse option value "auto"
[overlay @ 0x5574e72c46c0] Error setting option format to value auto.
[Parsed_overlay_2 @ 0x5574e72c45c0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5574e72c1900] Error initializing filter 'overlay' with args '(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto'

Comment: I use ffmpeg 3.3.4

Comment: You need a version from July '17 or later. For now, you can change `auto` to `gbrp`.

Answer (score 0):

The [delogo](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo) parameters do not support constants. The absolute values must be manually specified.